# Json parsing in fragments listview android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

i'm using tabs in activity_main.xml with 3 tabs each with a fragments... in tab1 i'm parsing json data in list view and it is generated successfully.... my question here is whenever i moved to other tabs and return to 1st tab the list in tab1 is generated again and it shows the data twice ..... i want to know how to get rid of that ..... THANKS IN ADVANCE

**FragmentA.class**

```
enter code here


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


ListView list;
TextView pm;
TextView sp;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  //URL to get JSON Array
  private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/json/apple.php";
  //JSON Node Names
  private static final String TAG_APPLE = "Apple";
  private static final String TAG_PHONEMODEL = "PhoneModel";
  private static final String TAG_SPECS = "specs";

  JSONArray model = null;
public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    new mparse().execute();
}
public void apple(){

    mlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
}
private class mparse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pm = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.phonemodel);
        sp = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.specification);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            model = json.getJSONArray("Apple");

            for(int i = 0 ; i< model.length(); i++){

            JSONObject c = model.getJSONObject(i);

            String phonemodel = c.getString(TAG_PHONEMODEL);
            String specs = c.getString(TAG_SPECS);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_PHONEMODEL, phonemodel);
            map.put(TAG_SPECS, specs);

            mlist.add(map);

            list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mlist, R.layout.list, new  String[] {TAG_PHONEMODEL}, new int[] {R.id.phonemodel});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.specification);

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = model.getJSONObject(position);
                        String sp = (String) obj.getString(TAG_SPECS);
                        TextView s = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.specification);

                        s.setText(sp);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            });
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
}
}
```

**Log cat**

```
12-22 18:36:35.286: I/Process(713): Sending signal. PID: 713 SIG: 9
12-22 18:36:38.366: D/gralloc_goldfish(728): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-22 18:36:39.256: D/dalvikvm(728): GC_CONCURRENT freed 188K, 10% free 6001K/6663K, paused 8ms+8ms
12-22 18:36:40.695: D/AndroidRuntime(728): Shutting down VM
12-22 18:36:40.695: W/dalvikvm(728): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x409961f8)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at  com.ss6.FragmentA$mparse$1.onItemClick(FragmentA.java:132)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-22 18:36:40.715: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are reparsing your stuff then readding it to mlist. Just do mlist.clear() before mlist.add()

Comment: @rupps on the same prog when i click on the list it gets error and closing the project .....

Comment: i added onitemclicklistener

Comment: It's probably the setContentView() in onClickListener() !! Mind that activity.setContentView() replaces the WHOLE activity layout, it will remove your fragment, listview and everything with freshly re-inflated instances (and your fragment will be gone) . Unless you are trying to do funky things beyond my knowledge, setContentView() should only be called once, after creating the activity. If you need to change the ListView stuff, creating a new adapter or better yet, replacing its data and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is the way to go!

Comment: @rupps as i tried to display that content in new activity .... is that possible to display in another fragment???? if yes means may i know how to do it ???

Comment: ideally you display the content in the activity / fragment you load it. You were not displaying it in a new activity, but were replacing the current activity (that includes all created fragments) with another layout, so effectively killing everything. You can place an empty listview in the fragment, then when you get the data, create an adapter then set the adapter to the listview in order to render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the webservice in **onResume** so each time onResume gets called the service will be called which inturn adds data to the list.

this section here

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(TAG_PHONEMODEL, phonemodel);
        map.put(TAG_SPECS, specs);

        mlist.add(map);
```

if you really wish to call the service in onResume , you need to intialize the list first to an empty list, such that if data gets added it would be to a fresh list.